# Centos : Configure yum to install from another machine in the network that has an outgoing connection

Tags: centos, proxy, yum, installation

Using Centos 5.4 here and I have two machines on the same network but only one has access to the outside world. I want to install software using yum on one machine, and rather than download the packages and copy them over manually, I'd like to set it up so it can use the other machine as a gateway.

Any tips on tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

install squid on the one that has access to the internet, and on the one that is NAT'd, configure yum.conf to use the other host as a proxy.

Comment: That seems to work cheers

Answer (score 1):

mrepo can do what you need: http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/mrepo/